# Modify argument without return

Tags: c

I have a problem in C. I have this function :

```
int test(void *data);
```

I want to change *data* with this function but I don't want another prototype (not use void **). Actualy, data equals null out this function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
test(void *data)
{
  data = "toto";

  return 1;
}

int
main()
{
  void *d;

  if (test(d) != 1) {
    printf("erreur\n");
  }

  printf("résultat : %s\n", (char *) d); // displays "résultat : (null)"

  return 0;
}
```

Help me please. ;)

Comment: I wonder why you want to avoid using `test(void ** data)`. The answer to your question is "Yes, but that's really bad practice" because it will be quite confusing and error prone.

Comment: `void *` can contain any object pointer. Including a pointer to another pointer. So `void **` is completely unnecessary, since a `void *` can represent a `void *`, a `void **`, a `void *****`, an `int *******`, or any other type of object pointer you care to store in it.

Answer (score 0):

In C arguments to function are passed by value. `d` is passed by value to function `test`. `data` is a local variable to function `test` and `d` is copied to `data`. The assignment

```
data = "toto";
```

makes pointer `data` to point to string literal `toto`, while `d` is unaffected of this assignment in `main` function. So, this assignment has no effect on `d`.

In `main` you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. This will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you. Can I avoid that without using int test(void **data) or void *test() ?

Comment: Yes. That's the way you can avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your *test* function, you change *data*, which doesn't affect *d* because *data* is just a local variable. If you really need to change *d*, then you need to let *test* return *data* and do *d=test(d)*.

Moreover, in your *test* function, the value of *data* is never used. So what is the point to have *data* as a parameter of the function?

In *printf("résultat : %s\n", (char *) d);*, you try to cast *d* into pointer to char and then print the value of *d*. Although you don't dereference *d*, you are still printing a variable that hasn't been initialized, which is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Any object pointer (i.e. non-function pointer) can be converted to a `void *` and back to the original type without altering the value. This means that you can pass any kind of (object) pointer to your `test()` function, it will be automatically converted to a `void *`, and you can then convert it back inside `test()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test(void *data)
{
  char **s = data;
  *s = "toto";

  return 1;
}

int main()
{
  char *res;

  if (test(&res) != 1) {
    printf("erreur\n");
  }

  printf("résultat : %s\n", res);

  return 0;
}
```

You just need to make sure that the `test()` function knows what the original type was.